# Why are two database tables (node and node_field_data) used for node data?

Tags: 8, nodes

I would like to understand the database architecture of Drupal 8. I noticed that Drupal 8 has two separate tables (node and node_field_data) which include almost the same columns. Can anyone give some clarification on this?

Answer (score 0):

To add additional information to @jaypan's answer following are my observations

**node_field_data** contains 6 fields

```
nid     int(10) unsigned
vid     int(10) unsigned
type    varchar(32) The ID of the target entity.
status  tinyint(4)
title   varchar(255)
uid     int(10) unsigned    The ID of the target entity.
revision_translation_affected   tinyint(4)NULL
```

the **nid** is primary key in this table and referred by node and other fields as target id. 
The **type** attribute tells what kind of content it is referring to, like posts, article or custom. In case of custom, it will store the name of the content type.

Comment: For me there are more fields, and the primary key contains node nid + langcode.